Error when $\right]$ is part of the example title
I noticed that when I use $\left[\right]$ in example title is throwing an error. Is a bug or is illegal use it?
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{example}[Interval $\left(a, b\right)\subset\mathbb{R}$]
        \end{example}
        
        \begin{example}[Interval $\left[a,b\right)\subset\mathbb{R}$]
        \end{example}
        
        \begin{example}[Interval $\left(a,b\right]\subset\mathbb{R}$]
        \end{example}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}




\left and \right in that context do nothing useful.

in
 \begin{example}[Interval $\left(a,b\right]

the optional argument to example is Interval $\left(a,b\right with an inline math that starts and does not end.
You need to hide the inner [] inside {...}
        \begin{example}[{Interval $\left(a,b\right]\subset\mathbb{R}$}]

This applies to any standard optional argument.
